# When submitting Google Action to production do you have to do alpha/beta first?

Tags: actions-on-google

I just submitted my app for production and it said "ok version 7 has been submitted" so I am hoping that the most current "draft version" is what was submitted, is that how it works?  I had an alpha version but then uploaded a new one, tested it myself a little, and then submitted for production without deploying to alpha first -- so in this case does the most recent uploaded "draft version" become the one that is submitted for production?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you submit to production, it is the most recent draft/current project state.

Comment: Thanks you're right, I realized that it states "Before you release the current draft version..." etc during submission.